# What's the difference between these two below?

Tags: java, regex

```
System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
System.out.println(matcher.group());
```

I like to know what's the difference between the above two codes. I get different outputs. Can anybody elaborate on this?

Thanks

Comment: For simple samples, I get the exact same values for group() and group(1): can you provide a specific expression and input string?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The call to `group()` gives you the entire string that matched, whereas `group(1)` gives you the first parenthesized "Capturing" group (or more generally, `group(n)` will give you the *n'th* capturing group, counting left/opening parenthesis, starting from 1).

So for example, if you had an input string like this:

```
The quick brown fox
```

And you matched against the following regular expression (without the quotes):

```
"The (\\w+)"
```

Then `group()` would give you "The quick" and `group(1)` would give you "quick".

For more details on how all of this regular expression stuff works in Java, look See the [`java.util.regex.Matcher`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28%29) JavaDoc.

Comment: This regular expression is missing something, didn't you mean "`The (\\w+)`" ? (and technically speaking, it will not match - `matches()`, it will be found - `find()` )

Comment: Updated to add the backslashes, and you are right about `matches()` versus `find()`.

Answer (score 2):

I point you to the JavaDocs for [Matcher](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group(int))

group():

> Returns the input subsequence matched by the previous match

group(int):

> Returns the input subsequence captured by the given group during the previous match operation.

Comment: Please use `> ...` to blockquote.

Answer (score 1):

The [API doc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group(int)) is a very good place to look first.